# How to use proxy with Snowpark session builder to connect to snowflake

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to using snowpark, recently released by Snowflake. I am using Intellij to build udf(user defined functions). However struggling to use proxy using Intellij to connect to snowflake. Below are few things I already tried:

1. putting proxy in Intellij (under Preferences)
2. adding proxy before building session
   `System.setProperty("https.useProxy", "true")`
   `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "xxxxxxx")`
   `System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "443")`
   `System.setProperty("no_proxy", "snowflakecomputing.com")`

Below is my code -
`val configs = Map (`
`"URL" -> "xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com:443",`
`"USER" -> "xxx",`
`"PASSWORD" -> "xxxx",`
`"ROLE" -> "ROLE_xxxxx",`
`"WAREHOUSE" -> "xxxx",`
`"DB" -> "xxxx",`
`"SCHEMA" -> "xxxx",`
`)`
`val session = Session.builder.configs(configs).create`

Comment: What exact error do you see when setting the proxy and executing the function?

Answer (score 0):

Snowpark uses JDBC driver to connect to Snowflake, therefore the proxy properties from JDBC connector can be used here as well.

In your Map add:

```
"proxyHost" -> "proxyHost Value"
"proxyPort" -> "proxyPort Value"
```

More information [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#specifying-a-proxy-server-in-the-jdbc-connection-string)

If you're specifying a proxy by setting Java system properties, then you can call *System.setProperty*, like:

```
System.setProperty("http.useProxy", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyHost Value");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort Value");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxyHost HTTPS Value");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", ""proxyPort HTTPS Value"")
```

or directly to JVM like:

```
-Dhttp.useProxy=true
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
```

More information [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#specifying-a-proxy-server-by-setting-java-system-properties)